# Winter Bash notifications do not live refresh

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, winter-bash, live-refresh, winter-bash-2022

The Winter Bash notifications do not work like in previous years:

Once you get a new hat, you need to refresh the page (or open a new page) to see a change in achieved hats, and then only a blue circle with a number shows (tested on FF and Chrome, both latest versions).

Notifications do not live refresh and also the color of the "snowflake" svg icon is not being changed, when a new hat has arrived. It used to look similar to this:

[image]

**Note:** The live refresh for Notifications for Inbox, Achievements and Reputation appear as supposed.

Comment: The snowflake can have a different color  ?!

Comment: @bad_coder yes it can and my example it is not the original color from last year, but couldn't find the right rgba pattern, anyway they'll remember...

Comment: I feel like being pedantic and saying these are *not* push notifications, as someone who has been pushing for them for quite a while. They're just notifications ._.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well, right now it is not a push notification, but I remember very well last year how I enjoyed seeing either the green for achievements/rep coming up once in a while, as well as the dark-pink whenever you got a new hat....

Comment: I've edited it to say 'live refresh' which is what it already is. Feel free to roll back if its incorrect, I won't... push... the matter >_>

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I used the term Push Notifications, following this article: [Push notifications for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270352/push-notifications-for-stack-exchange), but Live Refresh is fine for me too... a pity it doesn't work, though :)

Comment: No, such thing never existed, you remember wrong. That's still a valid feature request for future winter bashes.

Comment: @U12-Forward what was the meaning of your edit??? Of course I rolled it back, this question is about winter bash and it's not a discussion, but I wonder what led you to that edit. Also, super weird summary that got nothing to do with what you did. Are you using automated script or something? If so, don't.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start off by saying that our top bar has changed, code-wise, over the past year or so. There is a strong possibility that the snowflake worked this way at same point but for the life of us, we cannot find any code that would suggest this was ever a feature (or it was written in a different spot that has since been deleted).

We'd like to err on the side of caution here and not introduce this feature right before the holidays as it would introduce a new load (albeit small but could be abused) on our infrastructure. i.e. We would need to be hitting our Winter Bash API to poll for unread notifications, which we currently do not do. I wouldn't say this functionality is critical compared to inbox or reputation notifications, so we'll revisit this functionality for Winter Bash 2023!

Comment: Your response here indicates that this should be tagged as status-deferred, not status-declined, if you're planning on revisiting this functionality for the future.

Comment: @Blue and since this was never actually in place, that's a feature request and not a bug. I'll edit.